# Trouble Configuring Docker to Listen on Specific Ports in WSL2

Tags: docker, tcp, remote-access, wsl-2

I'm encountering an issue with configuring Docker to listen on specific ports in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). I have tried two methods: editing the `daemon.json` file and modifying the systemd `docker.service` file with `-H` flags. Despite these efforts, the Docker daemon is not listening on the intended IPv4 address (`0.0.0.0:2375`), but rather on the IPv6 loopback address (`::1`).

**Please note that I am trying to host docker on my Windows workstation and access it on my 2015 MacBook Pro for frontend development (I don't care much about connection security at the moment).**

**What I Have Tried:**

1. **Editing `daemon.json`**:

   - I added `"hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375", "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"]` in the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file.
   - After editing, I restarted Docker using `sudo systemctl restart docker`.
2. **Modifying systemd `docker.service` File**:

   - Initially, I had the `ExecStart` line as `/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`.
   - Later, based on suggestions, I removed the `-H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375` flags, but this didn't resolve the issue.

**Current Status:**

- Running `systemctl status docker` shows that Docker is active and running, and the logs indicate `API listen on [::]:2375`.
- However, when checking with `Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 2375` in PowerShell, it shows Docker listening on `::1` (IPv6 loopback), not on `0.0.0.0`.

```
daly@Daly-PC:~$  systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-12-24 20:04:40 CET; 24min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 2081 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 20
     Memory: 41.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─2081 /usr/bin/dockerd

Dec 24 20:04:40 Daly-PC dockerd[2081]: time="2023-12-24T20:04:40.682162156+01:00" level=warning msg="WARNING: API is accessible on http://0.0.0.0:2375 without encryption.\n         Access to the >
Dec 24 20:04:40 Daly-PC dockerd[2081]: time="2023-12-24T20:04:40.682200216+01:00" level=warning msg="WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_bps_device support"
Dec 24 20:04:40 Daly-PC dockerd[2081]: time="2023-12-24T20:04:40.682207886+01:00" level=warning msg="WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_bps_device support"
Dec 24 20:04:40 Daly-PC dockerd[2081]: time="2023-12-24T20:04:40.682211576+01:00" level=warning msg="WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_iops_device support"
Dec 24 20:04:40 Daly-PC dockerd[2081]: time="2023-12-24T20:04:40.682215876+01:00" level=warning msg="WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_iops_device support"
Dec 24 20:04:40 Daly-PC dockerd[2081]: time="2023-12-24T20:04:40.682228515+01:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=311b9ff graphdriver=overlay2 version=24.0.7
Dec 24 20:04:40 Daly-PC dockerd[2081]: time="2023-12-24T20:04:40.682251535+01:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Dec 24 20:04:40 Daly-PC dockerd[2081]: time="2023-12-24T20:04:40.693404023+01:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Dec 24 20:04:40 Daly-PC dockerd[2081]: time="2023-12-24T20:04:40.693452703+01:00" level=info msg="API listen on [::]:2375"
Dec 24 20:04:40 Daly-PC systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
```

**Questions:**

1. How can I properly configure Docker in WSL to listen on both the Unix socket and `0.0.0.0:2375` for IPv4 connections?
2. Are there additional settings or steps I need to consider to ensure Docker listens on the desired IPv4 address?

**Environment Details:**

- Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2)
- Docker version: Docker version 24.0.7, build afdd53b
- Operating System: 22H2 Build 22621.2861

Comment: Can you provide your Dockerfile? Does `docker ps` or `docker ps -a` show the same routes?

Comment: @ViaTech here's the output of that https://pastebin.com/Sqb4SGVR